# Unity Ads Mediation Android resolver failing to resolve dependency

Tags: unity-game-engine, mobile-ad-mediation

I'm facing issue mentioned above.

After Installing Package Ads Mediation, and when I go to: Assets > Mobile Dependency Resolver > Android Resolver > Resolve. I'm getting this issue: [see Android Dependency error.png](https://ibb.co/Kynpb9p)
I have installed all recommended [External tools](https://ibb.co/4pyWjvC) recommended by Unity with [LevelPlay Integration Manager](https://ibb.co/5sSzrSZ).

**I don't know what's wrong here???**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete all the dependency files located in your `Assets/Plugins/Android` directory.
Remove External Dependency Manager and Ads Mediation.
Then restart the project. Install EDM. Go to Assets > Mobile Dependency Resolver > Android Resolver > Setting enable Auto Resolve. Wait after adding each new package. Like for 2 min.
Should work.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me to fix this issue.